# Amazon AWS Lamda Function | event is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I wrote a lambda function that is triggered by a rest API gateway that I also created. The rest API has two parameters ingr and upc. The weird part is in the lambda function, the event object is actually undefined. I have been getting some weird interaction where whenever I try to link the lambda to the triggering gateway API, it will create a new ANY method inside of the already deployed gateway and I am not sure why it does that. I am allowed to delete that method though and then remove it from the trigger, it only showing the two-parameter trigger now but maybe this could be part of my problem?

[image: Image of API gateway resources and methods]

Here is my API gateway resources and method.

And below is the code to my lambda function.

```
'use strict';

const https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // API Key
    let app_key = process.env.API_Key;
    let app_id = process.env.APP_Id;
    
    let ingr = event.pathParameters.ingr != 'null' ? event.pathParameters.ingr : '';
    let upc = event.pathParameters.upc != 'null' ? event.pathParameters.upc : '';
    
    let optionals = ingr + upc;
    
    // Set the options for the https request
    const options = {
      hostname: "api.edamam.com",
      path: "/api/food-database/v2/parser?" + "app_id=" + app_id + "&app_key=" + app_key + optionals,
      method: "GET"
    };

    // Make the https request
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let body = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => {
            let response = {
                "statusCode": res.statusCode,
                "headers": {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "body": body
            }
            callback(null, response);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', callback);
    req.end();
};
```

Can anyone please help me figure out why the event parameter ends up undefined?

Comment: Why are you saying that `event` (or `path params`) is undefined? `...rs.ingr != 'null'` the logic looks like a not normal logic,  let's try `let ingr = event.pathParameters.ingr || ''`;

Comment: @hoangdv changing the logic to that wouldn’t change anything because the object event is undefined when I call for some reason. I would still get the same type error saying it can not find ingr because it’s undefined. The reason I know event is undefined is because I’ve printing it out in the console for testing and it always comes out undefined even when I correctly pass my parameters

Comment: Make sure that you're using Lambda-Proxy Integration to connect api gateway with lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to enable Lambda-Proxy like @hoangdv mentioned in the comments